# No ha sido posibe conectar con el sistema de archivos. Por favor, confirma tus credenciales. WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Tengo un problema con un wordpress que instalé hace poco, pasa que cuando quiero instalar algo me salta una pantalla que me pide credenciales de FTP, a lo cual jamas he tenido que colocar eso en ningún wordpress que he instalado, quisiera saber como puedo solucionar esto porque coloco mis datos de FTP y me salen errores como que usuario o contraseña incorrecta o conexión fallida, he probado una de las opciones que dice wordpress, a lo cual ya no aparece la pantalla que pide credenciales de FTP pero igual no me deja instalar nada me dice error. Uso xampp y estoy en localhost.

este es el código que probé:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

y también:

```
define("FTP_HOST", "localhost");
define("FTP_USER", "yourftpusername");
define("FTP_PASS", "yourftppassword");
```

gracias por sus aportes.

Comment: Deja solo el FS_METHOD a direct, pues los otros parámetros son para la conexión por medio de FTP y no te interesa. Si como bien dices, ya lo tienes y sigue sin funcionar, es muy probable que se trata de permisos aunque no estoy seguro porque eso nunca me ha pasado en un entorno "windows". Probablemente falte información en la pregunta para poder responderte con seguridad, por ejemplo, ¿qué error muestra el fichero error_log? ¿qué sistema operativo usas? ¿qué versiones y programas usas?.

Answer (score 0):

Has probado con éstos datos? En local no necesitamos autenticación de usuario y contraseña por defecto, sino pueba en poner la IP `"127.0.0.1"` en `FTP_HOST`

```
define("FTP_HOST", "localhost");
define("FTP_USER", "");
define("FTP_PASS", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando wordpress arroja un mensaje de usuario ftp normalmente es debido a permisos en los directorios. Asegurate de que los permisos sean 755 en caso de linux. En windows prueba a poner control total sobre los directorios y subdirectorios.

Tambien es posible que fuera por que el usuario configurado en el servidor no fuera correcto, asegurate que los permisos de las carpetas corresponden al usuario que instala el servidor web.